# set up solution for website app with cms panel using angularJs and asp.net web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, solution

I'm new to AngularJS and web API. I want to build a website that has 2 parts, first the website itself and second a CMS-panel, both using Angular and asp.net web API. 
My question is: What is the best practice to set up a solution in Visual Studio 2013?

- Should I use all of these Angular and asp.net API in one project?
  If no:
- Should I use project or website for angularJs parts?
- Should I use separate project/website for CMS-panel and the website?
- Should I use ASP.net mvc? (for bundling and  i donno ...) is it useful in my case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use two seperate projects, one for AngularJS Apps, another for Web API.
2. I recommend using nodejs and grunt for bundling and minification, jshint rules etc for packaging your angularjs app
3. You can escape from ASP.Net MVC and Web API only will work for you.
4. You can use John Papa's HotTowel, an excellent guide for writing apps in Angular
   https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel-Angular